# How to edit page in new sharepoint layout/version

Tags: sharepoint-online, html5

I always edit or customize page in sharepoint thru edit page and add html on the edit source.

[image]

But i have this new task and i was given a new sharepoint site and when i was about to start my work i noticed that it has a different feel and i can't find the edit source where i put my webparts and html codes. It feels like a drag and drop setup where customizing a site is very limited.

[image]

is there a way to convert this site to an older feel like the image above? or i'm just missing something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is new modern page look of SharePoint and it would be the permanent experience in coming days. For now if you want to return to classic view. Follow below steps

Go to All Site content page. (/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx)

On the left bottom corner you will find link to Return to classic SharePoint.

Click on it and you will get be redirected again to older version of UI.

Hope this helps... Happy coding.!!!!

Comment: If i don't see the "Return to classic SharePoint" does that means i don't have a full access on the site?

Comment: no...that is not case...you will not see this option if you are on modern page which we created manually... all OOTB pages are accessible via classic also if you are browsing OOTB modern page....

Comment: So there is no way i can replicate the custom wiki pages i created in the old sharepoint (Classic) to the new modern page?

Comment: You would have to create page again with modern layout....it cannot be switch automatically

Answer (score 1):

If you create a modern page, there is no OOB method to switch to classic page. We can create a separate classic wiki page in site content.

You can check the article which talk about [SharePoint classic and modern experiences](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f)

To add custom code to modern page, I recommend you use SPFx web part which is available on github by Microsoft called [react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor). You can install this webpart to your site collection and then use code to insert the html into an iframe.